# unable delete all selected checkbox rows in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

can anybody explain me how to delete only selected row or all selected row by checkbox it have below code but giving me error sql exception 

```
Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM usermaster WHERE id='28''
```

`public function actionMultipledelete() {
        if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {

            $keys=array();
           $keys = \Yii::$app->request->post('id'); // id is array
        }

        UsermasterModel::deleteAll(['IN','id',$keys]);
            return $this->redirect(['index']);

    }`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

> $keys = implode(',', $array);
>
> $connection = Yii::$app->db; $command =
>   $connection->createCommand("DELETE FROM usermaster where id IN
>   (".$keys.")");